# Bluetooth Mouse is being detected but is not getting paired

Tags: windows, bluetooth

I removed all my BT devices from my PC (win10), experimentally. Now I cannot pair them again.
For example, I enter my MS mouse to pairing mode and ask Windows to add a new BT device. The MS mouse is detected but does not get paired.

I tried updating the NT delivers (uninstall/restart).
Checked Windows integrity which is fine.

I tried a USB BT. Still cannot pair. I get the message

> Driver Error

In device-manager, "Generic BT radio" Is marked as erroneous. Properties say

> Cannot load driver

---

No trace of a BT device in Control Panel

I did a Windows reset. BT functiond supper well
until
Windows installed a big update. BT does not functions sny more

Comment: Restart the computer. Once restarted, look in Control Panel, Device Manager and then Bluetooth. Expand it and make sure no red or yellow marks. Close out, open Control Panel, Devices and Printers. What do you see in the way of Bluetooth.

Comment: How did you remove the BT devices?